# How to export .drawing file

Tags: swiftui, pencilkit

I'm trying to draw something in app with PencilKit. Now I want to export my drawings from my file, so I could open send it to other devices, and then open it(in format PKDrawing).

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
//user does drawing...
let data = canvasView.drawing.dataRepresentation()
```

`data` will be of type `Data`.  You can then write that to a file (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1414800-write) and export it however you want.

For example, you could use ExportFilesAction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDseNgvdTpA

To load this data back into a `PKDrawing`, you can:

```
let drawing = try? PKDrawing(data: dataToLoad)
```

Comment: Thank you!  So i can load data format in PKDrawing, but can i create this type of dataset with .drawing inside. For example, in sample app there is File Notes.dataset with .drawing file there.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you’re asking.

Comment: Unfortunately the export files action example in the provided link no longer works due to, presumably, Apple's changes.